# creating an ec2 instance from an image - finding kernel id attributes using boto

Tags: amazon-ec2, kernel, boto

I've got an EC2 snapshot from a running machine. When I create an image and then an instance out of it, it fails the reachability test, and I can't connect to it. I checked the volume and it's got no errors by attaching to another machine.

I now suspect that I have to choose the right kernel-id, and that the default might not be compatible.

Looking at other EC2 instances I have, they are running kernel id `aki-427d952b`, but this kernel is not available from the dropdown list (even in the same availability zone).

How do I find the next-best kernel id? Is there some list of kernel ids and which versions/architectures they support?

EDIT: can e.g. python boto or another library be used to list all kernel-ids and attributes to allow choosing a different kernel-id from `aki-427d952b` (which is missing from the dropdown list).

Comment: I see many related questions on SO that look very similar and weren't closed as off-topic. If it's not appropriate here, can this be migrated to serverfault? I also edited the question and am asking about using boto for this purpose. Hope this can either be re-opened or migrated to the most-appropriate stackexchange site.

Answer (score 0):

Boto can certainly be used to list images, and you can get data about their configuration.  Whether that's the best way to search for a replacement is another question, but, if you want to do it, here's the python/boto code

```
# use your AWS id and Secret here
conn = EC2Connection(awsid, awssecret)

# returns array of all images your account can use
all_images = conn.get_all_images() 

for img in all_images:
    attrs = img.__dict__
    # attrs will be a dictionary of key-value pairs associated 
    # with the image.  Look through them to find what you want.

    if img.kernel_id == 'aki-427d952b':
        print "found aki-427d952b:  imgid=" + img.id
```

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, I can also use `ec2.get_all_kernels(kernel_ids=['aki-427d952b','aki-...',...])`, but it still doesn't quite help me figure out which is the best kernel-id to choose to replace `aki-427d952b` unfortunately...

Comment: What's your criteria for "best"?

Comment: good point. I would say best == the most compatible (same architecture, same version, the least likely to break things if used instead of `aki-427d952b`)

Comment: You can look through the attrs in my example above for various attributes of the image.  You might be able to find enough information to make a choice, though "least likely to break things" unfortunately is something you'll have to guess at.

Comment: sadly even things like linux kernel version seem hard to tell from the dict :( I wonder if this information lives elsewhere then. Maybe boto doesn't have all the answers in this case?